# How to convert Exim emails downloaded via FTP so they can be imported into an email client?

Tags: email, imap, pop3

I have backup folders of emails that I downloaded from an old server running Exim.  I can open all the files in a text editor and read the contents and they are in standard RFC 822 format.

The filenames look like this:

`1284775865.H451571P15783.pre.press-themes.com,S=840363/2,S`

Ultimately I need to import them into a Google Apps account.  It's a free account so I can't use the python apps API method which would work if I added a .txt file extension.  Google has [Mac Email Uploader](http://code.google.com/p/google-email-uploader-mac/) but it requires the email to be in one of the following:

- Apple Mail: ~/Library/Mail
- Eudora: ~/Eudora Folder
  -Thunderbird: ~/Library/Thunderbird

When I try to import the messages into Apple Mail or Thunderbird they are not recognized.  I have tried adding a .mbox file extension and a .txt file extension.  I have also ran this bash script but it converted them all into one big file with a .mbox extension that can't be read by any of the clients.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# == 0 ]; then
echo usage ${0##*/} FolderName
exit 0
fi

for file in `find "$1" -type f`; do
   mbx="${file%/*}.mbox"
   mbx="${mbx//\//_}"
   cat "$file" | formail >> "$mbx"
    done
```

Comment: Looks like standard Maildir filenames - could you install a pop server like Dovecot, drop the files into you Maildir/new folder and then point Google apps at this (temporary) mail server to grab the mails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the page you linked to,

> The Google Email Uploader for Mac is a desktop utility for Mac OS X that uploads email archives from Apple Mail, Eudora, Thunderbird, and **exported Entourage mail (along with other mbox and Maildir archives)** to your Google Apps mailbox.

What you have is [Maildir](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maildir), but from your given example it seems the names have been mangled during the transfer: the `2,S` suffix is supposed to be separated by a `:` (or `;` in some systems), not by `/`.

The output of your mbox conversion script should be accepted directly by Uploader, too.

```
dir="${1%/}"
mbox="$dir.mbox"
find "$dir" -type f | while read name; do
    formail < "$name" >> "$mbox"
done
```

Comment: It worked adding the entire Maildir folder that included all the mailboxes.